# Call function in other method

Tags: php, function, class, methods, payment-gateway

I am trying to call *testFunction()* in the *$this->mollie->payments->create* method, but I get an error:

**Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Mollie_API_Exception' with message 'Error executing API call (request): The amount is lower than the minimum.'**

So this means that the *$this->testFunction()* returns 0.

I did the following test:

```
$test = new gtpMollieGateway();
echo $test->testFunction();
```

And this gives a right value (a calculated amount for my checkout).

So this means that I do something wrong with calling the *testFunction()* in the *$this->mollie->payments->create* method

**My code for creating a payment:**

```
// Create payment
class gtpMollieGateway {
    public $mollie, $price;

    function __construct() {
       $this->mollie    = new Mollie_API_Client;
       $this->mollie->setApiKey( 'myapikey' );
       $this->price         = new gtpCheckoutData();

       add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'gtpCreatePayment' ) );
    }

    private function testFunction() {
        return $this->price->getPrice( 'inclusive' );
    }

    public function gtpCreatePayment() {
       if( isset( $_POST['checkout_submit'] ) ) {
           $payment     = $this->mollie->payments->create( array(
                // Here is the problem
                'amount'        => $this->testFunction(),
           ));
           header( 'Location: ' . $payment->getPaymentUrl() );
       }
    }
}

$_mollie = new gtpMollieGateway;
```

**The class for calculating my amount:**

```
class gtpCheckoutData {
    private $tax, $price;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->tax      = get_option( 'gtp_theme_settings' );
        $this->tax      = $this->tax['gtp_tax'] / 100;

        if( isset( $_SESSION['shopping_cart'] ) ) {
            $this->price    = $_SESSION['shopping_cart']['total_price'] + $_SESSION['shopping_cart']['shipping_price'];
            $this->shipping = $_SESSION['shopping_cart']['shipping_price'];
        }
    }

    public function getPrice( $type ) {

        if( isset( $type ) ) {
            switch( $type ) {
                case 'exclusive' : 
                    $totalPrice = $this->price;
                    break;
                case 'tax' :
                    $totalPrice = $this->price * $this->tax;
                    break;  
                case 'inclusive' :
                    $totalPrice = $this->price * ( $this->tax + 1 );
                    break;
            }
            return $totalPrice;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its seems your payment gateway error, so check your payment integration guide.

Comment: @hardiksolanki he said the this error occurs when the `amount` is 0

Comment: You probably don't have $_SESSION['shopping_cart']['total_price'] defined. Can you do var_dump($_SESSION) and check if this exist inside session? Also you have too much coupling, try to re-factor your code

Comment: @Igor My session is set. I have checked this already by my test (see my question) which gave the right value. So this is not the problem. What do you mean with coupling?

Comment: I mean that for example gtpCheckoutData reads $_SESSION variable directly maybe would be better to inject values $_SESSION provides in constructor or provide some interface for that. But this all does not matter, it just makes harder for us to figure out where is a problem :) Does get_option( 'gtp_theme_settings' )['gtp_tax'] returns value which is not zero?

Comment: @Igor I understand what you mean. Yes that returns 21 (tax, vat)

Comment: The problem is that I cannot use $this->price->getPrice( 'inclusive' ) inside $this->mollie->payments->create( array() ).

Comment: Why dont you do instead of 

$payment = $this->mollie->payments->create( array(
     // Here is the problem
    'amount'  => $this->testFunction(),
));

do

$amount = $this->testFunction();
//print everything here
echo $amount; var_dumP($_SESSION); // and thing for taxes also
$payment = $this->mollie->payments->create( array(
     // Here is the problem
    'amount'  => $amount,
));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long time searching and trying I have found the problem. My session was not started in my plugin document. Wordpress loads the plugin before functions.php, and my session was started in functions.php.

So this was the reason that my value was 0, and that was occurring the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your function testFunction() is calling function function getPrice( $type ) and function getPrice( $type ) is returning 0 so may be because of 0 amount you are getting this error from external api (Payment gateway api).

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but that is what I am already saying in my question.